# What is eval_step in Experiment Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I do wonder what is the parameter 'eval_steps' in learn.experiment in tensorflow ? Why would you run over the evaluation set several times every time you want to evaluate your model ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your evaluation is a whole epoch, you're right that it doesn't make much sense. `eval_steps` is more for the case when you're doing mini-batch evaluation and want to evaluate on multiple mini-batches.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate on multiple mini-batches"? So, if we want to evaluate on the entire validation set, what shall we set the eval_steps to?

Comment: That depends on the input_fn. If the input_fn chooses random datapoints and puts them together (random minibatches), then there's no setting of `eval_steps` which will run exactly one epoch of evaluation (which may be totally fine). But as long as you set your input_fn to deterministically iterate over the evaluation data once, eval_steps can be `None` or a large number and it will stop once the input_fn runs out of data.